# Play youtube video using youtube api v3 in php

Tags: php, video, youtube, youtube-api

I am using [YouTube Data API(v3)](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) for accessing data of youtube.
I search a lot how can I play a video in PHP using this API, but I couldn't find anything.

I know there is a way to play YouTube videos.

1. Embed a video
2. Using iFrame

However, YouTube is blocked in region I live, which means I can't use any method from them.

Are there any workarounds?

For instance, [playit.pk](http://playit.pk)  can play videos even if region is blocked.

**UPDATE** 
how can `playit.pk` access YouTube video URL like.
`https://r2---sn-npo7en7d.c.doc-0-0-sj.sj.googleusercontent.com/videoplayback?upn=yS-T9e4J_3o&id=15589d4018f319ea&mime=video/mp4&mm=31&mn=sn-npo7en7d&ms=au&mt=1444897255&mv=m&ip=2400:6180:0:d0::27:f001&key=yt6&initcwndbps=13453750&ipbits=0&ratebypass=yes&sver=3&signature=A365AA3ADA506748AE53F0493B34E4B4AE807DCC.9F8EB21E86E4F5682BFFD44768102434DA58341B&fexp=9405958,9408710,9413271,9414764,9416126,9416359,9417707,9418204,9418400,9418809,9418997,9419837,9420351,9421923,9422553&nh=IgpwcjAxLnNpbjAzKgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&expire=1444918985&sparams=dur,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,nh,pl,ratebypass,requiressl,source,upn,expire&source=youtube&dur=408.090&itag=18&pl=48&requiressl=yes&lmt=1434858572379608`
If I found this kind of url I can play video very easily.
Can i access that kind of URL using `api v3` if not then how can they do that.

Comment: Probably by using a proxy. However, if youtube is blocked in your region.. would it be wise to make it accessible trough your own website? I don't know if there are any real risks involved but the fact that it's blocked probably makes it illegal.

Comment: But I think `playit.pk` not using proxy. what they are use. Because proxy is slow method.

Comment: Rephrasing, removing noise, code format, links

Comment: "Proxy is an agent or substitute authorized to act for another person or a document which authorizes the agent so to act" In most cases it means redirecting a call and thus bypassing certain restrictions. The following article might be of use to you: https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/proxy_setup